# sql server ce database lower version

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to create sql server ce database of 3.5 version using system.data.sqlserverce dll of version 4.0 using c#

The code I use

```
SqlServerCeEngine engine=new SqlServerCeEngine ()
engine.CreateDatabase()
```

Answer (score 0):

No you must uae the 3,5 version to do that